# Multithreading only way to play background music in Java?

Tags: java, playback

I have a game with game logic happening in the main. I just added sound playing as per documentation I found:

```
//////////////////////SOUND/////////////////////////
     SourceDataLine soundLine = null;
     int BUFFER_SIZE = 64*1024;  // 64 KB

      // Set up an audio input stream piped from the sound file.
      try {
         File soundFile = new File("tim ph3 samplepart1.wav");
         AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
         AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
         DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
         soundLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
         soundLine.open(audioFormat);
         soundLine.start();
         int nBytesRead = 0;
         byte[] sampledData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
         while (nBytesRead != -1) {
            nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(sampledData, 0, sampledData.length);
            if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
               // Writes audio data to the mixer via this source data line.
               soundLine.write(sampledData, 0, nBytesRead);
            }
         }
      } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         soundLine.drain();
         soundLine.close();
      }
     /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

It plays the file I specified out of the files in my project folder in Eclipse.

The problem? It blocks all game logic after it that appears in the main.

This makes sense - the program is sequential and until the ENTIRE song is done...I figure the game can't go on.

This obviously isn't going to work, and it appears I'm going to have to go to dreaded multithreading...BUT BEFORE I DO...I wonder...is there a Java library or some other clever solution to avoid multithreading in this case?

Comment: Multithreading isn't all that dreading. I remember feeling the same way before learning it, but its pretty logical. Debugging a bug that exists in some shared resource between threads, now *that* I dread :)

Comment: It is not the *only* way to play music, but it's the only way if you want to do anything else concurrently! In other words, you don't have a choice here. Learn how to multi-thread and have some fun with it.

Comment: D'awww okay I SPOSE I'LL LEARN SOMETHING haha

Comment: There is no library with a multitheading feature specific to anybodys needs. you have to do what you want, to do in threads/concurently yourself.

Comment: It's not threads that are tough, it's the interactions between threads. As long as your thread is just doing its own thing you'll be fine.

Comment: Wow...and as you all said I have both my main soundtrack and sound effects working. This is really not so bad, given that I don't have to have any threads interact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a separate thread. There's nothing to be afraid of. Multithreading in Java is a piece of cake. Look at the Concurrency packages.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

Beware: knowing how to start a thread and knowing how to safely multithread your programs are 2 different things. For now, make sure you avoid touching the same music from multiple threads.

Comment: Right on - I have multithreaded in C some in some classes I've been in and it scares me because of the Pandora's box you mention. Thankfully all I want is my main thread, the music player, and maybe a chat, so this is no biggie!

Comment: Cool. As long as no object is shared between threads you've got nothing to worry about. Luckily Java has several classes and measures to support synchronized operations - so really, you mainly need to watch out for deadlock. (I.E. A needs B to release C before it can continue, B needs A to release C before it can continue)